# How can I refresh a list in one component after form submit in another component that shares same parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this structure:

```
<users admin component>
   <user list component>
   <new user form component>
</users admin component>
```

I am not using any type of global state management (ie redux) and would like to avoid it if possible.  I am using hooks to manage state on each component.

[image]

What I would like to do is update the user list component (GET) when the POST call succeeds in the form component.

What is the best way to accomplish this?  Is it more common to somehow add the new item to the existing list of users or just refresh the list with another GET?  How do I accomplish the correct solution?

Theoretically, at what point is it time to bring in some type of global state management such as Redux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I like to avoid using global state where it isn't needed. As a rule of thumb, you should consider in how many places you need to use the data and how "far away" are they from each other. For example in your case it's not needed, because your components are very close together and the data isn't used anywhere else.

In order to pass the data around easily, you should [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). This means that your parent `UsersAdminComponent` should hold the state and only pass the values and callbacks to the children.

Here is an example of how I would do it:

UsersAdminComponent.js

```
const UsersAdminComponent = () => {
    const [setList, list] = useState([])

    return (
        <>
            <UserListComponent list={list} />
            <NewUserFormComponent setList={setList} />
        </>
    )
}
```

UserListComponent.js

```
const UserListComponent = ({ list }) => {
    return (
        {/* displaying the list here */}
    )
}
```

NewUserFormComponent.js

```
const NewUserFormComponent = ({ setList }) => {
    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        fetch(...)
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => {
                setList(previousList => [
                    ...previousList,
                    ...data.newElements,
                ])
            })
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            {/* form contents */}
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I actually started to do, but instead of simply passing the setList, I was trying to make it more difficult by trying to create another function to redo the refresh api call.  I like this approach better, cleaner and saves api call.  Still getting an error saying data.json is not a function.
axios
      .post(url, payload)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then((data) => {
        refreshUsers((previousList) => [...previousList, ...data.newElements]);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

Comment: The `.then(data => data.json())` is only needed to parse the data if you are using `fetch`. If I remember correctly, axios is already parsing the data for you and you can omit this part :)

Comment: Yes that's what I thought also so I removed it.  However, now i'm getting another error wich I posted above in the original post.  Ugggg, hope that doesn't get me in trouble with the SO police, I can't post the image in this comment as far as I can tell.

Comment: You should adjust the fetching part of the code to your data. I completely guessed what the result of your API might be to give an example of how a solution might look

Comment: Hi All, please help me in resolving my question: My question is also similar o this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74851741/react-how-to-refresh-part-of-page-on-form-submit